# Getting parent>child1_1>child1_1_1>child1_1_1_1 structure only from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns, like:

```
name | id | parent_id

XYZ  | 1  |   2
ZYX  | 3  |   1
YXZ  | 4  |   3
```

Is it possibile to retrieve just from the mysql query a result that can be simply read as string like "parent>child1_1>child1_1_1>child1_1_1_1" and so on? The hierarchy tree has a maximum depth of 4 and the "parent" has parent_id=0. It gives me headaches to build it in php.

To be more specific, the parent category has multiple children, which also have multiple children ... I want to get all the records like "Computer>Networking>Routers", "Computer>Networking>Switches" etc. results.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this is done using recursive ctes,  mysql doesn't support it

As your depth is only 4 levels, you can use `self left join` to connect the parents like below

`concat_ws` is used to concatenate the names.

updated the answer to get the deepest child id, for this need to use `coalesce`

```
select  coalesce(t3.id,t2.id, t1.id) as deepChildId, 
        concat_ws('->', t.name ,t1.name, t2.name, t3.name ) as childList
from Table1 t
left join Table1 t1
on t.id = t1.parent_id
left join Table1 t2
on  t1.id = t2.parent_id
left join Table1 t3
on  t2.id = t3.parent_id
where t.parent_id =0
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! It works like a charm, but now I have another issue and I don't really know how to manage it. I need another column with the id of the deepest category (child). If I just "SELECT t.id, concat_ws[...]" I get the parent's id.

Comment: @valicu2000, updated the answer for this, you can use `coalesce`